# perforce linux server in case-insensitive mode

Tags: perforce, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

Was setting up a test perforce server on linux, and found out its case sensitive.  How can I switch the server to case insensitive?  Is this possible? Would the server need set up again?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you set the case sensitivity when the server is set up for the first time, and don't change it when there's already data in it.  Since you're still in the testing stage, I'd assume it's fine to just blow away your test data and start over from scratch.

Converting existing data is possible, with a bunch of caveats that are detailed in this article: https://community.perforce.com/s/article/1200